# Will there be some kind of widgets for Unity ? 

Tags: unity

Will there be some kind of widgets for Unity ? somethign like KDE has already ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so, there will be more indicators afaik (such as indicator-weather) but I doubt there will be any widgets.  If you want widgets, give screenlets from the software center a try.  http://screenlets.org/index.php/Home

{edit}
you can actually run Plasma in unity -- see http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-run-kde-plasma-widgets-in-ubuntu-unity/